# How to find parametric equation of the line which is perpendicular to 2 lines and passes through point of intersection?

Tags: vectors, parametric

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{lcccc}
 \mbox{Line}\ 1 & : &  x = 1 + 2a, & y = 2 - a, & z = 4 - 2a
\\[1mm]
\mbox{Line}\ 2 & : & \!\! x = 9 + b, & \,\,\, y = 5 + 3b,
& \,\,z = -4-b
\end{array}\right.
$$
Point of Intersection: $\left[7,-1,-2\right]$.

How to find parametric equation of the line which is perpendicular to these $2$ lines and passes though point of intersection ?.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

The coefficient vector of the parameter $a$ represents the "direction vector" of that line, and taking the cross product with another vector will give a perpendicular direction.

Answer (score 1):

Take a plane $\alpha$ passing through the point and perpendicular to line 1.
Take a plane $\beta$ passing throught the point and perpendicular to line 2.
The intersection $\alpha \cap \beta$ is the line you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The parametric equations of lines are:

$L_1$: $\frac {x-1} 2=\frac{y-2}{-1}=\frac{z-4}{-2}=a$

$L_2$: $\frac {x-9} 1=\frac{y-5}{3}=\frac{z+4}{-1}=b$

So the gradients of normal to the plain containing two lines are:

$(l, m, n)=[2\times1=2, 3(-1)=-3, (-2)(-1)=2]$

Therefore the equation of required line is:

$\frac{x-7} 2=\frac{y+1} {-3}=\frac{z+2} 2=t$

You can find x, y and z for t and find similar equation as lines $L_1$ and $L_2$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
\mbox{Line}\ 1 & : & \vec{r} =
\overbrace{\phantom{A}\vec{r}_{1}\phantom{A}}
^{\ds{\pars{\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 2 \\ 4\end{array}}}}\ + a\
\overbrace{\phantom{A}\vec{n}_{1}\phantom{A}}
^{\ds{\pars{\begin{array}{r}2 \\ -1 \\ -2\end{array}}}}
\\[1mm]
--- & -- & -------------
\\[1mm]
\mbox{Line}\ 2 & : & \vec{r} =
\underbrace{\phantom{A}\vec{r}_{2}\phantom{A}}
_{\ds{\pars{\begin{array}{r}9 \\ 5 \\ -4\end{array}}}}\ + a\
\underbrace{\phantom{A}\vec{n}_{2}\phantom{A}}
_{\ds{\pars{\begin{array}{r}1 \\ 3 \\ -1\end{array}}}}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}

---

The answer is given by
\begin{align}
\mbox{} &
\\
\bbox[10px,#ffd,border:1px groove navy]{%
\pars{\begin{array}{c}x \\ y \\ z\end{array}}} & =
\pars{\begin{array}{r}7 \\ -1 \\ -2\end{array}}\ +\
a\,\vec{n}_{1} \times \vec{n}_{2} =
\pars{\begin{array}{r}7 \\ -1 \\ -2\end{array}}\ +\
a\verts{\begin{array}{r}
\hat{x} & \hat{y} & \hat{z}
\\
2 & -1 & 2
\\
1 & 3 & -1
\end{array}} =
\pars{\begin{array}{r}7 \\ -1 \\ -2\end{array}}\ +\
a\pars{\begin{array}{r}-1 \\ 4 \\ 7\end{array}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbox[10px,#ffd,border:1px groove navy]{%
\pars{\begin{array}{rcr}7 & - & a\\ -1 & + &4a \\ -2 &  + & 7a\end{array}}}
\\ &
\end{align}